# Why is argsort called argsort?

Tags: numpy

So, it's an indirect sort that returns the indices that would sort an array.  Why is it "argsort" (which makes some sense given that it takes an argument -- the type of sort to use) but not "indirect_sort" or something like that?  Or get_sort_indexer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for argsort gives numpy as first result, so it might indeed be a bit uncommon name. This might be something historic, apparently it already existed [in 1997 in Numeric](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/comp.lang.python/numeric%2420argsort/comp.lang.python/heUdCcW0PFc/YZ_Bm0EkKhsJ), a predecessor to Numpy.

I would guess they came up with that name as a parallel to [argmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max), which seems to be standard mathematical function that is implemented in many languages (numpy, mathematica, ...), even though the analogy is not perfect.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Basically viewing an array as a list of pairs (array index, value at that index), the array index could be seen as the "argument", and "arg sort" therefore could be taken to mean "index sort".  The latter would make more sense to a larger population I would think.  Thanks!

Comment: Ooh, nice historical note!  I thought it might have something to do with historical use.  Most cryptic names do.